# An example of a sequence of functions that is not pointwise convergent

Tags: partial-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

I've been searching for an example of a sequence $f_n(x)$ of functions that is not pointwise convergent, i.e.:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left | f_n(x) - f(x)  \right | = 0$$
but I cannot find one.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of functions defined by $f_{n}(x)=(-1)^n(x)$. Can your prove that this doesn't converge pointwise?

**hint**: let $\epsilon=\frac{x}{2}$.

A more simple example would be: $f_n(x)=(-1)^n$ (for each $n$, $f_n$ will be a constant function.)

More generally, just let $f_n(x)=a_n$ for any divergent sequence $\{a_n\}$

Comment: $f_n(x)=n$ is another example.

Comment: True. I guess I wanted to emphasize that it need not diverge to infinity.

Comment: Small edit to state (what I take to be) your main point